# Play: unable to find valid certification path to requested target with ws.acceptAnyCertificate=true

Tags: ssl, playframework, ssl-certificate

I am using a really old version of Play 2.4.x and in my unit tests I have a test consuming an endpoint which has changed its SSL verification and since then I've been getting the following error

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

In order to ignore this at least for the test environment I added this property on the test application.conf

```
ws.acceptAnyCertificate=true
```

Nevertheless, the error persists. Is there any other configuration property I can use to ignore SSL verification and trust all certificates?

// EDIT
I have also tried

```
play.ws.ssl.loose.disableHostnameVerification=true
```